# Image masks (polygons) need to be fed into a grid and obtain the percentage of the grid mixels covered by the polygon

Tags: python, numpy, mask

I have a mask in .ply format that I am working with using pymangle quite happily. However, I want to plug all the polygons in the mask to a 2x2 grid with 1/100 or so subpixels so that I get the percentage of coverage of each grid pixel due to the mask. I do not know how to approach this. Is it the same as the mask weights?

For each pixel I should get a value ranging from 0 to 1 depending on how much of the pixel is covered by the mask.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? The way you described, a pixel can be covered or uncovered by a polygon. How can it have a partial opacity?

Comment: It is basically feeding a polygon(randomly oriented) into a fixed grid. This would result in some pixels being partially covered. (Imagine overlaying a triangle on a fixed rectangular grid.)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED using pymangle over numpy meshgrid.
pymangle has a 'weight' function that can be used to get the weight of the mask in a coordinate point (0 if the mask doesnt exit there).

```
mask = pymangle.Mangle('/path/to/file.ply')
M = mask.weight(ra,dec)
M.reshape(ra.shape)
#Here ra,dec is a numpy meshgrid
```

Comment: Hi! Can I ask you to show more code examples? Your solution might be useful for my tasks.